# AngularJS Non-Modal dialog

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create non-modal dialogs in my AngularJS app. These dialogs will act as popups with complex HTML that show when users hover over table cells.

Is there an easy way to get NON-Modal dialogs working. All existing implementations I have found use modal dialogs.

Comment: What you mean with - "NON-Modal dialogs"?

Comment: Non-modal or modeless dialog boxes are used when the requested information is not essential to continue, and so the window can be left open while work continues elsewhere. A type of modeless dialog box is a toolbar which is either separate from the main application, or may be detached from the main application, and items in the toolbar can be used to select certain features or functions of the application.